# How to link a click event with an event that didn't upload yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample

**my JS code sample:**

```
$('.owl-next, .owl-prev').on("click", function() {
    alert("1");
});
```

There is a click event on two buttons, the problem is that these two `div`'s configure consecutively, and the event I need doesn't work.

I need a suggestion how to make the click event on the two buttons work, even if the buttons appear later.

My javascript code uploads too quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "appear later" ? why don't you attach event on document ready ?

Comment: `dives`? What is this word

Comment: @DhruvJoshi I think he means `DIV`s

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.ready()`. It won't set the code unless the site content and it's components are fully loaded.

**Note**: this solution doesn't work for asynchronous calls, used for dynamical adding elements into DOM. If you want to add your elements dynamically, check following link: 
[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.owl-next, .owl-prev').on("click", function() {
    alert("1");
  });
});
```

Comment: You are right. Also, it is good to write script tags at the end of the body tag.

Comment: @user218046 Exactly.

Comment: if the buttons appear later dynamically.Then your code will not work?

Comment: Actually he didn't mention that his buttons are loaded dynamically.

Comment: `I need a suggestion how to make the click event on the two buttons work, even if the buttons appear later`.I think he mentions this.

Comment: If it's loaded dynamically so he is using asynchronous calls. He didn't even tag the `asynchronous` keyword...

Comment: @ Kind user if he creates button using javascript then?Just make some edit so you answer will be good one.

Comment: @Hekmat Made some edit. (: